# Crash on constructor of DbContext of my EFCore class in Android

Tags: c#, android, entity-framework, xamarin.forms

I developed an app which works flawlessly on UWP using EFCore 2, Xamarin Forms but when i run the same in Android, I am getting an crash on constructor of my DbContext class. sometimes the exception is timed out getting an excpetion and sometimes it is:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DiagnosticsLogger1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory+Infrastructure]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
```

the constructor is empty and am out of ideas as to why this is happening. I am using Xamarin Forms 2.5.0.121934 and EnterpriseFrameworkCore SQLite 2.0.1

```
public class InspectionContext : DbContext
    {
             //some members here

            public static InspectionContext Create(string databasePath)
            {            
                var dbContext = new InspectionContext(databasePath);             
                dbContext.Database.Migrate();
                return dbContext;
            }
            public InspectionContext(string databasePath)
            {
                DatabasePath = databasePath;
            }
    }
```

I call the above using this:

```
var database = InspectionContext.Create(databasePath);
```

> There is another query with the same error as mine but it's in the Portuguese forum. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/265476/erro-efcore-com-sqlite-no-xamarin-forms-android

Comment: Are you using an `IoC` container?

Comment: no, i added the code to the original post.

Comment: Use try catch to get the exception.

Comment: I solved this issue. I had earlier used linker option to User Assemblies and SDK. I changed it to NONE. then deleted all OBJ/bin folder, rebuilt the project and deployed it to device. Then executed it, it didn't occur. earlier i had set Linker option to user assemblies/sdk due to another issue about Unsafe assembly and it was one of the suggested option.